# Why can't specify sensor delay for gyroscope

Tags: android, gyroscope

As we know we can specify the sensor delay as an absolute value (in microseconds) above Android 3.0 (API Level 11) from this [link](http://java.llp2.dcc.ufmg.br/apiminer/docs/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html).

I tried it for accelerometers, it really worked. I set the time delay for 2s, and the interval showing the acceleration is about 2s.

However, for gyroscope, no matter how much I set the time delay, the  gyro outputs the value in its own time delay.

Anyone know the reason?

Comment: I have a suspicion that this is device dependent... Post what device you are using, it might help.

Comment: @ppeterka The phone is Nexus S, android 4.1.2. It's really tricky...

Comment: How did you set delay for accelerometer ?

Comment: @Nadosh Just as this: mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer , sensorDelay); where sensorDelay is the predefined as a number before this line.

Comment: test your with hardware 'Gyroscope Log' app also let me know vendor of gyro.

Comment: Thanks! I found that it's related with the device. I tested it using another mobile phone, it worked fine. @ppeterka U are right.

Comment: You're welcome, it was just a guess :)